# Should we cut [corners]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corners) (syn. [corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corner)) has no wiki, 0 followers and some 173 questions. I skimmed through all of them and "corners" is used as one of:

- Corners of a drawn shape (some graphics object or canvas) or GUI component
- Alignment in a GUI (e.g. bottom-right)
- [Corner case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case)
- [CSS corner shaping](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-4/#corner-shaping) (or other HTML+CSS-related which I'm not qualified to distinguish between)
- [Corner detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection)
- [rounded-corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounded-corners) (appears as [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounding) + [corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corners))

Corner detection algorithms might be worth their own tag. Otherwise, I'm not sure if we need this ambiguous tag at all or just add a wiki explaining what it should be used for. 170 questions isn't too much to fix manually if a small team goes for it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think that corner detection algorithms deserve their own tag as it is a similar case to OCR. I suggest [corner-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corner-detection) for these.

In the cases of visual corners, the specific visual elements and functions used give a better tag classification. The word "Corner" in the titles will complement that.

"Corner case" is too abstract and it is unlikely to have any beneficial effect on the question.

Comment: "corner case" would be a meta tag if it existed.

Comment: If not retaggable to one of the testing-related tags.

Comment: All questions where [tag:corner-detection] was applicable were re-tagged.

Comment: Can you check on this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319817/does-the-rounded-corners-tag-add-any-value

Answer (score 13):

## Progress

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:

- flag or close questions that are off-topic/unclear/too broad/etc;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments

All questions where [corner-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corner-detection) was applicable were re-tagged. Please review this tag in addition to [corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corners).

Here are some easy queries:

[corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corners)
[Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorners%5D+closed%3Ano) 0
[Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorners%5D+closed%3Ayes) 0
[No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorners%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0
[No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorners%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0

[corner-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corner-detection)  is cleaned and what is left is on-topic
[Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorner-detection%5D+closed%3Ano) 38
[Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorner-detection%5D+closed%3Ayes) 10
[No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorner-detection%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) 6
[No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorner-detection%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) 16

[Review in the Close vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=corners&filter-tags=corner-detection)

If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room.