# Does the 'rounded-corners' tag add any value?

Tags: discussion, tags

Given rounded-corners are often implemented differently across different systems I can't think of a situation where someone would want to query this tag.

Looking at editing suggestions I'm seeing people who search rounded corners and [add this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11785560) to a bunch of questions. Maybe I'm missing something but what is the use case for this tag?

Comment: I guess it's like [tag:arrays], which is really only useful in combination with a language tag; [tag:rounded-corners] should usually go with [tag:css] or some UI framework tag.

Comment: Note that [tag:corners] itself [was burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295233/should-the-corners-tag-be-burninated-removed-from-all-questions).  Not sure if that says anything about [tag:rounded-corners].

Comment: If people use it, it clearly adds value.

Comment: @DeerHunter not necessarily many times the original poster didn't use the tag and an editor comes through adding it to every question which mentions the phrase. Presumably they're doing this to gain a badge. 

Adding it just to add a tag in order to get a badge is not a legitimate use of a tag. I'm asking for situation in which someone would search it. I think the in use with another language tag makes some sense but at the same time is there really any depth to rounded-corners as a subject?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give my personal view as the one who asked [Should the corners tag be burninated (removed from all questions)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295233/should-the-corners-tag-be-burninated-removed-from-all-questions) and dug into this a bit back in the day.

It's true that [rounded-corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounded-corners) are achieved differently and come with their own problems and questions in every language. However,

- There are many tags of this nature in UI (and in general), like [border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/border) and [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/padding). People can query for those in addition to other language tags, like [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)+[padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/padding) which makes sense. Additionally, they help specialize the question so you won't have all GUI questions in C++ tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)+[gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui) without specifying what GUI element you are talking about just because it is different for every language.
- Before [corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corners) was removed, people also tagged rounded corners questions as [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounding)+[corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corners) (which is bad since the former is about numerical rounding). I fear that if [rounded-corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounded-corners) would be removed then people would still use [rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rounding) as an alternative.

To conclude, I can't tell if the tag "adds value", but removing it might cause a mess. As far as I could tell, the tag was unambiguous: rounded corners is a visual property of a displayed element which makes its corners rounded.

[image]

Comment: Is more complete a query about [css] + "padding" since it doesn't rely on any user adding consciously the tag, but on the actual content of the question.

Comment: @Braiam No standard is being recommended or enforced, so you can't rely on that.

Comment: Not sure why would that matter anyways? I'm not relying on standards, but if you want to "search" something SE search sucks, Google do wonders and tags ain't a way around it.